# Extract each line using shell script and assign it to variables and save it individually as new file

Tags: shell

I have file that contains many lines. Each line has the following information:

```
xxxxx,2017-06-26 13:12:53.750,-9.5949,124.6654,23.29,xxxx,yyyyy,mb,5.0,

xxxxx,2017-06-24 07:27:07.700,-41.2392,80.6425,10.0,xxxx,yyyyy,mb,5.2,

xxxxx,2017-06-24 02:37:18.140,-19.4438,34.509,24.44,xxxx,yyyyy,Mww,5.6,
```

I want to extract each line using shell script and assign it to variables and save it individually as new file. The content of output file should be like this:

```
YEAR=2017

MONTH=06

DAY=26

HOURS=13

MIN=12

SEC=53

MSEC=750

LAT=-09.5949

LONG=124.6654

DEP=23.29

MAG=5.0
```

Comment: checkout `while read` a file in `bash` with `IFS=,` . It may help.

Comment: **and assign it to variables** - what for?

Comment: To use it as input file for other script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is an example to read and parse the file (I called the data file "data.txt"):

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=,

# read lines like: xxxxx,2017-06-26 13:12:53.750,-9.5949,124.6654,23.29,xxxx,yyyyy,mb,5.0,
while read xxx1 datetime lat long dep xxx2 xxx3 xxx4 mag; do

  # input lines are partly split
  echo "Read $datetime"
  echo "lat=$lat long=$long dep=$dep"

  # parse datetime field which is like 2017-06-26 13:12:53.750
  date=$(echo $datetime |cut -d" " -f1)  # -d tells the field separator
  time=$(echo $datetime |cut -d" " -f2)  # -f tells the field number to extract
  echo "date=$date time=$time"

  # extract year value from date, which is like 2017-06-26
  year=$(echo $date |cut -d"-" -f1)

  echo "year=$year"

  # go on this way to fill up all the variables...
  # ...left as an exercize...!

  # after this comment, down until the "done" keyword,...
  # ...you will have all the variables set, ready to be processed

done <data.txt
```

When this script is run, it shows the following:

```
user@machine:/tmp$ ./script.sh
Read 2017-06-26 13:12:53.750
lat=-9.5949 long=124.6654 dep=23.29
date=2017-06-26 time=13:12:53.750
year=2017
Read 2017-06-24 07:27:07.700
...
user@machine:/tmp$
```

As noted in some comment, read about the read command and cut(1) command. Hope it helps.